# Can I pass through It.Is<> to another method to set up a mock?

Tags: c#, moq

I have this:

`myObj.SetupSomething(It.IsAny<string>());`

then in MyObj class:

```
public void SetupSomething(string s)
{
  _someMock.Setup(c => c.DoWibble(s));
}
```

The above code does not work work, because `It.IsAny<>` comes through as `null` so it sets it up with `null` instead of any string.  If I replace it with this:

```
  _someMock.Setup(c => c.DoWibble(It.IsAny<string>()));
```

Then it works ok. So I'm wondering, can I pass the expression of `It.IsAny<string>()` through to my method so that Moq still recognises what I'm doing, or do I need to make an extra `SetupSomethingForAnyString()` method (which is kinda nasty)?

Comment: `It.*` are meant to be used in setup expressions. they will default to their default value if you try to pass them as parameters

Comment: I figured Moq would just have an `ItIsStringType : string` class with the info about 'Any' and other configs, which is passed in, meaning that as long as c# continues to pass the original string as an object, it would preserve through multiple functions.

Comment: String is a sealed class, which demonstrates why subclassing wouldn't be a viable implementation for a completely generic `It.IsAny<T>()` matcher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered, the short answer is 'No', it's not possible to just pass a raw `It.IsAny<string>()` result as a parameter to a setup. But that's not really the end of the story. There's some incredible nuance to how Moq detects expression arguments and transforms them into matchers that are ultimately used when providing return values during actual execution. If you have the time, I definitely recommend taking a peek into the source. There's some cool gymnastics happening there-- and it's not just expression tree analysis.

At the most basic level, the reason that using `It.IsAny<string>()` as a parameter outside of a setup doesn't work has to do with the order of execution. Consider:

```cs
var x = It.IsAny<string>();
mock.Setup(m => m.DoWibble(x));
```

vs

```cs
mock.Setup(m => m.DoWibble(It.IsAny<string>()));
```

It the first, `It.IsAny<string>()` is evaluated outside of any mock context, and outside of the mock context, the library can't really return a meaningful value, so it just returns `default(T)`. That null value is then bound as a variable which is captured in the quoted lambda expression, `m => m.DoWibble(x)`.

That whole expression is passed to the `Setup` method, and the Moq library will partially evaluate the expressions provided for the arguments, including the captured value, 'x'. The current value is `default(string)`, so it will set up a matcher that will only work if the null value is passed.

In the second, the quoted expression now includes the entire `m => m.DoWibble(It.IsAny<string>())` call. Now when Moq partially executes `It.IsAny<string>()`, it's in a context where it can cooperate with an observer to perform side-effects, informing the Moq library to create the 'any' matcher for that argument.

But that means that Moq can detect a call to `It.IsAny` methods even if it's not directly invoked as part of the original quoted lambda. That means that this works as well:

```cs
Func<string> callIsAny = () => It.IsAny<string>();
mock.Setup(m => m.DoWibble(callIsAny.Invoke()));
```

The key here is that `It.IsAny<string>()` isn't actually invoked in the statement prior to the setup, but instead is only evaluted while Moq is analyzing the arguments to the mocked method. And because it sets up a detection context to see when `It.IsAny` is invoked, it can correctly create the matcher for this case.

Note that this isn't documented anywhere in the Moq usage guidelines, so I'm not sure if the fact that this works is intended. The detection context for It.IsAny is likely only intended to be there for setting up event handlers. But it's certainly cool, though!

---

Instead, if you want to actually pass argument matchers through some layer of indirection, it seems best to utilize the feature already present in Moq: `It.Is`.

It would be defined as:

```cs
public void SetupSomething(Expression<Func<string, bool>> stringMatcher)
{
   _someMock.Setup(m => m.DoWibble(It.Is(stringMatcher)));
}
```

Used like:

```cs
myObj.SetupSomething(_ => true); // match anything
myObj.SetupSomething(s => s == "a"); // match only calls with "a";
```

It's not as readable as using the normal `It.IsAny` call, but you could alleviate that by including your own matcher lambda as a property or method call (e.g., `Match.Any<string>()`)

At that point, it seems rather like re-implementing the domain language of Moq though. It's up to you if it's worth the effort.

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive reply!